# recordset cannot find record

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi all i have this situation in VB for Access.
[image]

GenraReport_Click() is the main function called when pressed a botton in the report.

Temp is a table containing some data like this:
[image]

Now i created a recordset rs to loop each record of Temp , by the field Item.
And it works , the problem is when i call the function prices that has to do exactley the same thing but on the field price.

The problem comes when i try to call rs!price (or rs![price] i tried both), it tells me that there are no records. I put a movefirst call at the end of the first loop to start again with the new function.

(i tried to do the main loop with price instead of item and it works so it's not the table and not the syntax the problem. What can it be?

Comment: my ideas about the problem : does , rs!field consume the record so a first loop delete all records from recordset? or , maybe the movefirst doesnt work and remains to the last element?

Comment: a) questions should include actual code, not pictures of code b) VB.NET IsNot VBA, not clear which one you are using, looks more like vba.  See [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

Your `Do Until` loop is likely exceeding the number of records available in recordset, so compiler errors out at 'No Current Record'. Usually, the proper way to loop through a recordset is to set the iteration limit to the [Recordset EOF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821459.aspx) property:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim s As String, i As Integer

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("temp")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

s = "": i = 1
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
   Do While Not rs.EOF  ' OR Do Until rs.EOF

      Select Case i
           Case 1
           s = CStr(rs!Price)

           Case Is < rs.RecordCount
           s = s & ", " & CStr(rs!Price)

           Case Else
           s = s & ", and " & CStr(rs!Price)
      End Select

      i = i + 1
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
End if

rs.close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: At the beginning that was the idea , but the last two element to be concatenated in the string by the loop have something different. Example if elements in table are 1,2,3,4,5 the output string should be : 
"1,2,3,4 and 5".

Comment: See update with example. Consider building your concatenated string with conditional statements, comparing a loop iterator with `rs.recordcount`. Here I use [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx), an alternate of multiple conditions If/Then